# Attribute float makes parent element ignore its height

Tags: css, css-float

I think seeing the effect live is better than posting code here. So you can find it here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9GGTr/4/)

As you see, the Add button is on the border. If there was no float set for the button, everything would be perfect. As soon as I set float (be it left or right), the box doesn't expand as much as it should.

Any idea how to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the parent element - http://jsfiddle.net/9GGTr/5/

Comment: Also keep in mind that you need to apply a width in order for the overflow to respond properly in some version of IE

Comment: @cale_b good point - adding width/height always a good idea for cross-browser consistency as well

Answer (score 1):

You just need to clear your float with clearfix or with "clear:both" css style:

http://jsfiddle.net/BumbleB2na/9GGTr/6/

This will put the floated element back in to the "regular flow" of the page, allowing its container to respect width and height of the floated element.